# How can I sort contacts by date added?

Tags: contacts

Is there a way to sort contacts by date added, or at least see contacts that have been recently added? I'm running android os 2.2.

Comment: for 2015, "Recent Contacts" is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is useful if you want programmatic and CLI access to your contacts in sorted order.

If you're on Android then most probably your phone contacts are synced with your Google account's contacts which you can access using [Google Contacts](http://google.com/contacts). Now, using the [Google Command Line Tools](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) you can return contacts in order of filing if no other sort method is set.

For example, use the following command to get all contacts in a text file in recently added order:

```
google contacts list ".*" > output.txt
```

Cheers.

Comment: This worked a treat. Just make sure you run this from cmdline like so `c:\googlecl\google contacts list ".*" > output.txt` - if you are in interactive mode it will print to screen, which is less useful.

Comment: wait hold on - this does not seem to order by date (?)

Comment: This does not work anymore - googlecl [does not work anymore since 2015](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googlecl/issues/573).

Comment: GoogleCL development has continued, and it seems to be working, but is definitely in beta https://github.com/vinitkumar/googlecl

Answer (score 4):

As most of the applications mentioned did not work anymore two approaches worked for me now (Aug 2020):

- Recent contacts app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ibtidah.tav.reco
- Following the approach of Owen Miller on Quora (https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-organize-Google-contacts-by-date-added) just getting the results via the api explorer at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and using the api url
  https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=25&start-index=1&orderby=lastmodified&sortorder=descending

**Update 2022-03**
*Contacts API is being deprecated. Migrate to People API to retain programmatic access to Google Contacts. See https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration.*

**Steps to use the api:**

1. Open the playground website: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
2. Open Step 1, expand "People API v1" and click the url below (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts) then the blue button "Authorize APIs" (login with your Google account if not done already and grant permissions)
3. Open Step 2 and just click the blue button "Exchange authorization code for tokens"
4. Open Step 3 and put the url `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=25&sortOrder=LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING&personFields=names,metadata` into the "Request URI" field and click the blue button "Send request"
5. Find your results on the right in the "Request / Response" textarea.

- `pageSize=25` limits the shown contacts to 25
- `sortOrder=LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING` sorts the results by last modified date, descending
- `personFields=names,metadata` limits the returned results to contain only names and metadata [plus basic info]

See also

- https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list for parameters
- https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#SortOrder for possible sort options.

Comment: I like your second approach, but I ran into an issue with it. Somehow the sorting is messed up because it is using the wrong `updateTime` field to sort on. I found a solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668824/google-people-api-ordering-by-the-update-time-not-working-as-expected) 
To the Request URI you can add:
&sources=READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** I made an app for this called [Quis](http://quis.co/), and would love to hear if it solves your problem :)

**Longer answer:** Android doesn't save the date you added contacts, unfortunately. However, there is a trick: you can sort contacts by their "raw ID" in the database, which roughly increase over time. It's not perfect, meaning that it will more or less work for recent contacts, but definitely won't work for contacts added years ago since a lot of things probably happened since then – new phone, Google merging/syncing contacts, and various third-party apps messing with the contacts database.

I wanted this so badly I actually made [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.quis.quis) for it. It stores the date and location of newly added contacts, and also uses the above trick for contacts added before using the app. Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it might vary by carrier, but I only see options to sort by first or last name. (Motorola Droid, unrooted, Android 2.2.1)

I also don't see any apps in the Market that would display contacts sorted by date added.

I'm not even sure "date added" is captured.

If you're syncing with Google Contacts you might be able to kludge something together by applying a group to all of you existing contacts ("Old Contacts"?) then, whenever you review your contacts anyone without such a label is, by definition, recently added.

It is, as I said, kludgy. I don't see any other way to do it.

Comment: I see the same on my Galaxy S.

Comment: Contacts in gmail also only lets you sort by first/last name.  Doesn't seem to store when the contact was added either.