# How can I sort contacts by date added and have the addition date for each of them?

Tags: contacts

Is there a way to sort contacts by date added, and have the addition date for each of them? I am aware of [How can I sort contacts by date added?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5749/12202) but none of the proposed solutions display the addition dates.

I use a Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III with a rooted Android 4.1.2.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.