# How do I undo imported contacts?

Tags: contacts, bluetooth

It started when I wanted to backup my Mom's contacts online in my email. I took backup of her contacts in a `.vcf`  file and transferred it into my phone via Bluetooth. Later that day, I wanted to go to the Bluetooth folder but I couldn't find it. Neither can I find the `.vcf` file.

I went to Bluetooth menu -> received files and clicked on the `.vcf` file (not a real file, just a link). To my further surprise (read 'frustration'; the file existed) all the contacts of my Mom got imported into my phone. Android didn't ask me to import them.

Moreover, I have no idea where is  that file located.  I searched the storage (`extsd` & `SD0`) and nothing came up.

Comment: If you'd synced your contacts with the Google account earlier then you may remove that account, delete all the contacts (take their local backup first), add your Google account, and sync the contacts. It should be same as what undo would do. Alternatively, sort the contacts using date/time and then delete them. There are many related apps in market. You may also look at [How can I sort contacts by date added?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5749). If you've root access, and you want to get your hands dirty then edit the contacts.db yourself. Simply sort contacts based on ID or time there.

Answer (score -1):

FromNokia 3310:
                                Contacts => Option => Share Contacts => Mark => Back => Done => Blue Tooth sharing screen comes => More  => Select BlueTooth Device => conn.

In Android Phone
Go to contact => More (option in top right side) =>Settigs => Import Export Contacts => Import VCard files(VCF) from your device storage to contacts on your device

Comment: The OP doesn't asked to import from .vcf, bluetooth received vcf file got imported to his contacts and he needs to remove those and find vcf file.